# Why is this block of code here?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to implement Firebase Sign Up and I did not understand this part

```
 private void createAccount(String email, String password) {
    Log.d(TAG, "createAccount:" + email);
    if (!validateForm()) {
        return;
    }
```

I am referring to [this code](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/EmailPasswordActivity.java) from GitHub

The part Where if `validateform()` is unclear.

Please help.

Comment: bro `validateForm()` method use to check email, password validation before network operation. if user filled incxorrect email pattern u can validate by your side

Comment: @AbhishekSingh It's my first time in making a login screen and I am 17 so sorry

Comment: You ask **us** why did **they** do it. Why? Why don;t you ask **them**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that call validates the values that the user entered into the form, before sending those values to the server to create an account with them.

This type of client-side validation can improve the experience of the users of the app, since they get more immediate feedback in case they entered some invalid data.

For the precise form validation that the app performs, have a look at the [code of the `validateForm` method in the same file](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/EmailPasswordActivity.java#L187). In this case it catches empty username and password, which would indeed be rejected by the Firebase Authentication server.